# Grunt watch: livereload reloads 1 step behind…

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

here's my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        hologram: {
            generate: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.yml'
                }
            }
        },
        libsass: {
            files: {
                src: 'src/scss/style.scss',
                dest: 'templates/static/css/style.css'
            }
        },
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 8000,
                    hostname: 'localhost',
                    base: 'docs/',
                    livereload: 35729
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            scss: {
                files: ['src/scss/**/*.scss', 'templates/static/css/*.css'],
                tasks: ['libsass','hologram'],
                options: {
                  livereload: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Load plugins.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-libsass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-hologram');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect','libsass','hologram','watch']);

};
```

And here's my package file:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-hologram": "0.0.4",
    "grunt-libsass": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "author": "Yann Bettremieux",
  "homepage": "..."
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine. When I go to `http://localhost:8000/` I see my site and when I save my watched files the page reloads etc. **But**  it doesn't actually reloads the previous changes. Meaning, the first time I edit a SCSS file to say `color: blue`, I see in the inspector that some CSS livereload files are loaded but there is no change on the page. If I change the CSS to `color: red` the page reload but show everything in blue… If I change it to green, it reloads and shows me the everything in red, etc. etc.

I tried tu use the chrome livereload extension insrtead but it didn't change anything.
I tried grunt-sass instead of libsass. Same behavior.

Not sure what else to try to resolve this issue. Any pointer in thr right direction much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Livereload Readme already addresses the issue. See [live-reload-with-preprocessors](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#live-reload-with-preprocessors):

> Any time a watched file is edited with the livereload option enabled,
>   the file will be sent to the live reload server. Some edited files you
>   may desire to have sent to the live reload server, such as when
>   preprocessing (sass, less, coffeescript, etc). As any file not
>   recognized will reload the entire page as opposed to just the css or
>   javascript.
>
> The solution is to point a livereload watch target to your destination files.

You should enable livereload only for css files.

```
watch: {
    scss: {
        files: ['src/scss/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['libsass','hologram']
    },
    css: {
        files: ['templates/static/css/*.css'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks… Unfortunately, sometimes it works as expected and sometimes it works as I previously described even with your code. I can't reliably recreate the behavior consistently. When I start the tasks with `grunt`it never works the first time I save a SCSS file, but it does after 3-6 saves and if/when it starts working, then it's all good until I stop grunt watch.

Comment: Are you sure that you did it exactly that way? I was using this approach without issues. Config can be a bit different for you, but the idea itself is to listen for changes on the result css files.

Comment: I pretty much copy + pasted you answer (only changed the second `scss` key to `css`). Still somewhat mysterious… BUT I managed to get a consistent behavior with your setup: the first time I make a change and save, it doesn't work. But if I save the first change twice in a row (save again without making any changes) at the beginning, then it behaves as it should for all subsequent changes. So there's still something wrong with the setup but in the meantime, it's usable… Thanks!

Comment: Shoot, almost there but still not really usable. And another question: are you sure that location `templates/static/css/*.css` covers all css files generated from scss?

Comment: Yep. I'm concatenating everything in a single CSS file. That's part of the changes I made to get the current "improved" behavior.I guess I stumbled upon a not so obvious edge case… I'll update here if I figure it out. Thanks for all your help!